# Calculating Cloud Opacity for a location using EUMETSAT SEVIRI raw data

Tags: satellite, cloud-cover, cloud-gis

I'm using EUMETSAT SEVIRI raw data (EO:EUM:DAT:MSG:HRSEVIRI) to try calculate cloud opacity. However I am struggling to find a way to calculate it using the different channels that are offered. How can I use this data along with other data (surface albedo etc) to calculate cloud opacity for a location?